# firebase database queries and returns value true, but still goes forward if user exists, and register a duplicate entry

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This returns whether or not there exists a user, only when there is email already registered, if I use a different email the process still goes forward, I think I am not using a return value correctly.

This stays only if the email is registered. If I used a different email, it won't stop the process.

[image: This stays only if the email is registered, if I used a different email, it won't stop the process]

```
private void checkUsername() {
    final String Username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    //Check early for the username length
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Username)) {
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").getRef();
        final Query UsernameReference = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(Username);
        ValueEventListener UsernameValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String usernameExist = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                //If the username not null
                if (usernameExist != null) {
                    //If username exist
                    if (usernameExist.equals(Username)) {
                        editTextUsername.setError("username taken");
                        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        //If not exist, proceed here, which mean success

                        //Change to your edit text
                        String email = null;
                        String password = null;
                        createAcc(email, password, Username);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };
        UsernameReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(UsernameValueEventListener);
    } else {
        editTextUsername.setError("Username too short");
        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
    }

    final String email = (editTextEmail).getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    //validate email

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        editTextEmail.setError("please enter a valid email address");
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Username)) {
        editTextUsername.setError("username required");
        return;
    }

    if (!PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password).matches()) {
        editTextPassword.setError("password must contain an uppercase, a special character, and numbers");
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        editTextPassword.setError("password required");
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        editTextEmail.setError("email required");
        return;
    }
    if (Username.length() < 5) {
        editTextUsername.setError("Username too short");
    }
}

private void createAcc(final String email, String password, final String Username) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
    progressDialog.show();
    //creating a new user
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Uid
                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        User user = new User(
                                Username,
                                email);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                .child(uid).setValue(user);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, AgeDetailsActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        //display some message here
                        editTextEmail.setError("Email already exists");
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonSignup) {
        checkUsername();
    }
```

Comment: I have difficulty to understand. Can you explain more detail one by one?

Comment: so the first part is, TextUtils username string checking if the username's empty or it matches with Firebase database, if it is matching it should throw an error, the fetching part it does as you can see, but doesn't return the error, it straight goes into registering a new username with a different email, if and only if the string check is complete it must go to createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but it's ignoring the string check and creates username with duplicate entry.

Comment: So, you put the TextUtils at onCreate?

Comment: i have edited this, and put up the whole method here, everything seems to be fine in the method, but it still doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to prefer something like this, try this one.

```
 private void checkUsername(final String Username) {
        //Check early for the username length
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(Username) && Username.length() < 5) {
            DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            final Query UsernameReference = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(Username);
              UsernameReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String usernameExist = dataSnapshot.child("Username").getValue(String.class);

                //If the username not null
                if (usernameExist != null) {
                    //If username exist
                    if (usernameExist.equals(Username)) {
                        editTextUsername.setError("username taken");
                        editTextUsername.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        //If not exist, proceed here, which mean success

                        //Change to your edit text
                        String email = null;
                        String password = null;
                        createAcc(email, password, Username);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    } else {
        editTextUsername.setError("Username too short");
        editTextSekolah.requestFocus();
    }
}

private void createAcc(final String email, String password, final String Username) {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering...");
    progressDialog.show();
    //creating a new user
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //Uid
                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        User user = new User(
                                Username,
                                email);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                .child(uid).setValue(user);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, AgeDetailsActivity.class));

                    } else {
                        //display some message here
                        editTextEmail.setError("Email already exists");
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
}
```

Comment: it's not working, and i have pasted the whole method.

Comment: in the run, its just this...  
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: firstly the username > 5 is always true, so removed that and checked, then this line has the error
 String usernameExist = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); here.

Comment: @SunnySpilner actually I wrote the code `username < 5` . can you check what is the value for the datasnapshot? by doing like this. `String usernameExist = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));` . and add new line. `Toast.makeText(this, "username: " + usernameExist , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show;` . see what happen.

Comment: usernameExists! = null, is always null
also its giving me the same error on compile. "failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String"

Comment: @SunnySpilner I updated the answer. btw, if it still not working, may you share the database?

Comment: https://imgur.com/5LNWV1z this the database, all those duplicate entries are failure to see the Username entry already exists.

Comment: @SunnySpilner remove the `getRef()`

Comment: String usernameExist = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
this thing still giving the same error,  is the value of database here cannot me mapped to the string, is that what's going on?

Comment: do you mind to teamviewer? or just solve here? @SunnySpilner

Comment: Thank you so much Zuhrain!!, obvious mistake it was passing on to the create method..

Comment: @SunnySpilner no worry comment here if need help.

Comment: @SunnySpilner I know where is the error in my code. check it out.